# I have 2 "Columns folders" in SSMS 2016 CTP 3.1

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016

As pictured below (using SSMS 2016 CTP 3.1) I have 2 Columns folders under each table... I've tried restarting SSMS, etc... they persist.  What's going on?

[image: 2 Columns folders]

Comment: I have the same bug. They seem to work consistently, so it seems to be only a cosmetic issue. The performance with cloud databases is more annoying for me.

Comment: I also have performance issues with Azure, I doubt however that one has to do with the other, although I did seem to notice a little bit of an improvement with the update to ctp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue has been fixed in SSMS, but won't be available until after the 3.2 (SSMS December preview) release. *Source: [Microsoft connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2103116/columns-appears-twice-for-each-table-in-ssms-connected-to-azure-sql-database)*